# Stack button fail

Tags: ios, xcode7, uistackview

Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3.1. iOS 9. Storyboard. I have 7 rows of four labels across. I was intending to select each row to place it in a stack. Saw this technique in Hagerty's iTunes U (Stanford). Each time I select a row and press the button to add the four across to a stack, it makes these huge rectangles... They have a width of 127,000,000. I keep trying different things, adding all suggested constraints, getting rid of all contstraints, etc.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? TIA

Sorry, I'm apparently not allowed to add images as yet here... The rectangles on the View Controller are all UILabels. When I select a row of them and press the Stack button, next to pin, etc., it appears to make one wide rectangle, all 4 on top of each other, this last time is was 27,216,026 pixels across. I think the comment about not using "suggested" constraints is probably a clue... there certainly seem to be more than necessary. There are also some where I tried to delete a constraint where the constraint item appears to be dimmed. There are one or two where the dimmed one, and an exact copy of the dimmed are both there...

There are no images on the view... the only button is up top, a "Back" button.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to do this?

Comment: There's no code involved. I meant to say Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2. This is on the Storyboard. I am trying to get a view controller to be Auto Layout-ed so that it can rotate 90 degrees and redraw the screen... I select the rectangles on the view and press the "Stack" button.

Comment: Can you send us a screenshot of it maybe?

Comment: Are the buttons images?

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me the clue. It turns out that there are some bugs in the constraints setup, especially when using "suggested" constraints. I deleted all the constraints, then added just the minimum needed, made sure they were all perfect, and I got one row to work properly. Now I can do the others. 
After I do this enough times I am sure it will make sense, there is probably one constraint mechanism that doesn't work as it should - an Xcode bug. One adds size constraints both in the size inspector, and potentially the constraint mechanism, and sometimes they do not match. Those things have to be fuddled with until they do... and then Stacking works...